# Knowledge of exact reference folder in google drive

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, directory

I have 3 method in vb.net , the first for creation folder () as parent reference , the second for creation subfolder(parent reference ) as parent reference , the third is file creation (parent reference)

my probleme is in event button after existence test , i need to know the reference exactly

when i create subfolder , i need to know what's the folder reference exactly

```
 Dim ref As ParentReference
    ref = folder_creation()
    Dim res As ParentReference
    res = subfolder_creation(ref)
```

but the result is always false

this is how i call it

```
If (exist(f.selecteditem) = True) Then
        MessageBox.Show("exist folder , verify subfolder")

                    'here i want to know the folder reference exact
```

all traitement are in google drive

Comment: How are you creating the folders? What API methods are you using?

Comment: I used google drive api v2 , and i solved the problem , i change return type of exist method

Comment: good job, post your answer for the community

Comment: first , i used exist boolean method , i changed the type to string and return folder id (if exist ) else return null